# Python3 sorted function checking the same conditions twice

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort an array of numbers and return the largest number in string format.
For example:

```
 Array = [5,1,9,30]
```

should return

```
'95301'
```

I have the following code that accomplishes it

```
class LargestKey(str):
    def __lt__(x, y):
    print("x",x,"y",y, x+y > y+x)
    return x+y > y+x

class Largest():
    def largestNumber(self, nums):
        mapResult = map(str, nums)
        num = ''.join(sorted(mapResult, key=LargestKey))

testNum = Largest()
print(testNum.largestNumber([5,1,9,30]))
```

According to the print in the LargestKey function, the output is:

```
x 1 y 5 False
x 9 y 1 True
x 9 y 1 True
x 9 y 5 True
x 30 y 5 False
x 30 y 1 True
95301
```

I don't understand why the checking with x = 9 and y = 1 is happening twice

Comment: Wouldn't 30 be the largest element in your array?

Comment: I think it should return "30951" according to your idea

Comment: Based on the example I assume the idea is to arrange the numbers such as to create the largest possible output number, in which case it should indeed start with the 9.

Which would then mean we want a lexicographic comparison